# SQL Filter products from one table basing on attributes from second one

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have table with products

```
id | product_name

 1 | Product 1
 2 | Product 2
 3 | Product 3
```

... table with atributtes:

```
id | attribute

 1 | big
 2 | orange
 3 | expensive
```

and table with products and their attributes

```
id  | product_id | attribute_id

 1  |     1      |  1
 2  |     1      |  2
 3  |     2      |  3
 4  |     3      |  2
```

and what I want is to filter big, orange products.. in this case: Product 1

Something like:

```
SELECT product_name 
  FROM products as a 
  JOIN products_attributes as b ON a.id=b.product_id 
 WHERE b.attribute_id = 1 OR b.attribute_id=2
```

will not work as it returns Product 3 as well..

This doesn't work too, of course:

```
SELECT product_name 
  FROM products as a 
  JOIN products_attributes as b ON a.id=b.product_id
 WHERE b.attribute_id = 1 AND b.attribute_id=2
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add atributtes table into your `SELECT` statement and

filter by `attribute IN ( 'big','orange' )`

`GROUP`ing with `HAVING` clause should be added to satisfy the both conditions at the same time

```
SELECT p.product_name
  FROM products as p
  JOIN products_attributes as pa
    ON p.id = pa.product_id
  JOIN attributes a
    ON a.id = pa.attribute_id  
 WHERE a.attribute IN ( 'big','orange' )
 GROUP BY p.product_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.attribute) = 2
```

using `IN` rather than `OR` operator is more straightforward to use .

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44c6d58b3226d594dc0f4e0b5ab4190c)</kbd>

Comment: But I don't know the product_id - that's the point.... :)  And there will be much more products filtered than one... In this case I could just do: ```SELECT product_name FROM products where id= 1``` , don't I?

Comment: This will only work if he already knows what the product id is. And if he knows it, just what is preventing him to simply select its name from the products table?

Comment: Even after edit your query fails because it returns Product3 as well.

Comment: I'm able to back right now, and saw your comment is right, thanks. Then, fixed the statement due to the fact that the both conditions(`big` and `orange`) should be provided at the same time @El_Vanja .

Comment: Works now, there's just a slight typo on your line `JOIN atributtes a`... the double "t" should be the first one.

Comment: What if they are big, orange and expensive?

Comment: You will have to change last line to ```HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.attribute) = 3 ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find products that have multiple attributes, first we need to join the attributes table with itself:

```
SELECT pa1.product_id FROM products_attributes as pa1
JOIN products_attributes as pa2 ON pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
    AND pa1.attribute_id = 1 AND pa2.attribute_id = 2
```

This will output 1, which is the correct id. Note that it doesn't matter which of the two tables you will select the product_id from, since you're joining it with itself and both will contain it.

Now all we need is the name, so we're going to join the products table as well and change our selection:

```
SELECT p.product_name FROM products p
JOIN products_attributes as pa1 ON pa1.product_id = p.id
JOIN products_attributes as pa2 ON pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
    AND pa1.attribute_id = 1 AND pa2.attribute_id = 2
```

This should output "Product1".

Comment: Thank you - it's working too... I will have to compare efficiency with  Barbaros Özhan solution.

Comment: I believe his approach will prove to be better for a higher attribute count. Mine would need extra joins for every attribute added, while his will maintain the same number of joins.