# MySQL query matching 1 or more properties from a subtable

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP as script language and want to query some tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `objects` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Object 1'),
    (2, 'Object 2');

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'property1'),
    (2, 'property2'),
    (3, 'property3');

CREATE TABLE `lookup` (
    `objectId` INT(11) NULL,
    `propertyId` INT(11) NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `objectId_propertyId` (`objectId`, `propertyId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `objectId` (`objectId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `propertyId` (`propertyId`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `lookup` (`objectId`, `propertyId`) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3);
```

Now I have a multiple selection form (HTML checkboxes), where a user can select one or multiple properties (from the properties tabgle) and search for suitable objects having those selected properties.
For one property (e.g. property with id = 2) it is easy as I can use:

```
SELECT name
  FROM objects
 WHERE id IN (SELECT objectId FROM lookup WHERE propertyId = 2)
```

But how can I get objects having multiple propertyIds?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.  From what I can figure, it sounds like you need to use JOIN to join all three tables together for your query, and not use a subquery.

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561433/sql-filter-products-from-one-table-basing-on-attributes-from-second-one) is of any help. It's a similar issue.

Comment: @Strawberry: Have added the sql queries now

Comment: @Russ: By joining all three tables how will the WHERE clause look like?

Comment: @El_Vanja: I already saw the page, but it doesn't seem to be answered. In addition it doesn't fit my question/requirement

Comment: That's interesting, because I managed to solve your question by using the answer from that question - see [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0300d/2).

Comment: @El_Vanja: Awesome! I didn't understood the HAVING clause. But now in your example on fiddle I understood. Many Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: Incidentally, where you have a UNIQUE index comprising of all the columns of a given table, you can be reasonably confident that that's your PRIMARY KEY